# log4j2.properties cannot config slf4j loggers used by imported package

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I have some issue creating a `rootLogger` inside `log4j2.properties` file.

As you can see from my `log4j2.properties` file below, I have defined the `rootLogger` with `level` of `info`, and point it to the `rolling` appender `RollingFile`.

However, when I run the program, only the logs generated from my packages will go to the rolling file appender, with the correct log level specified, which is `info` in this case.

But the logs generated from the packaged I imported (my dependencies, for example, `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer`) are not written into the rolling file. Instead, it is printed on the console, and it is not with the specified level `info`, because even the DEBUG logs are printed out. It looks like the `rootLogger` I specified is never created and effective.

In one way, why the rootLogger is not working? ; in another way, how I can control the logs generated form the imported packages?

BTW, I am using the `log4j2.properties` in this way:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/my/log4j2.properties [options] xxx
```

log4j2.properties:

```
status = info
name = PropertiesConfig

property.directory = logs
property.filename = kafka.log

appenders = console, rolling

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${directory}${sys:file.separator}${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${directory}${sys:file.separator}kafka-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
#appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
#appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 50MB

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = kafka
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRefs = rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

### Update 1

I found the issue but look for a solution.

The issue is: I am using `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` but the packages I imported are using `org.slf4j.Logger`. This is why my `log4f2.properties` is not able to control the loggers from the imported packages (for example, [kafka-clients](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients)).

Then, my question is: how can I solve this issue?

### Update 2

I have tried to import `log4j-slf4j-impl` into my project by putting it in `pom.xml`. It is not working.

## Update 3

After I imported `log4j-slf4j-impl`, I saw this :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:xxx1]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:xxx2]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Then, I look back all dependencies and their dependencies, and found that, one of them is depending on `logback`, and this logback is containing it logger binder, which is complicating with the binder in `log4j-slf4j-impl`.

So I added the following inside this dependency within pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aaa</groupId>
        <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Boom! Problem solved! The loggers of slf4j is using the `log4j2.properties` I give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by myself. Please see the Update 1, 2, 3 in the question part.